# Can't write to aux file from cmd

Tags: miktex, automation, auxiliary-files

I have an automating script written in Java to generate a PDF file from a source tex file. The?main tex file may reside in one drive say 'C:' and one included file via `\input` in another drive say 'D:'. The path for included file was given fully. When I run `pdflatex` from `cmd`, it complains about unable to write `aux` file and stops there. But if I run `pdflatex` from TeXWorks, it runs fine and generates PDF completely. What could be the issue here? Please note I have a MikTeX console version is 4.2.

I invoked 'pdflatex' from 'cmd' using

`pdflatex -jobname=foo bar.tex`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `-jobname` is used for output pdf file name actually, but not the output directory path. What I missed is another option called `-output-directory=OUTDIR`. After changing the invoking `pdflatex` command to include `-output-directory` it worked.